# Wordpress page is getting the global header instead of the secondary header

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Im new with Wordpress, I'm trying to build a website which has one global header in all pages except the front-page.php, but my front-page is getting the global header instead of the unique header. The front-page has a  with a hero image before the  that when you scroll down the navbar will stick to the top. The other pages will have the same navbar but it will be placed directly in the top instead at the bottom. The code of the unique header (header-new.php) that I want in the front-page is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Page Title</title>

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Montserrat:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--  Main CSS File -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero">
    <div class="hero-container">
      <h2 data-aos="zoom-in">Let's get to work.</h2>
        <ul data-aos="fade-up">
          <li>Personal Trainer</li>
          <li>Posing Coach</li>
        </ul>
      <a data-aos="fade-up" href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </section><!-- End Hero -->

  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div id="navbar-container">

      <div class="logo d-block d-lg-none">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/dark-logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
      </div>

      <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul class="nav-inner">
          <li class="nav-logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/dark-logo.png" alt="Nav Logo" class="img-fluid logo-image"></a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html#hero">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="./personal-training.html">Personal  Training</a></li>
              <li><a href="./posing-lessons.html">Posing  Lessons</a></li>
              <li><a href="./macros-calculation.html">Macros-Nutrition</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="./get-started.html">Get Started</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->
```

The code for the global header (header.php) that will appear in all other pages:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta content="" name="descriptison">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Montserrat:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Main CSS File -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="logo d-block d-lg-none">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/dark-logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
      </div>

      <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul class="nav-inner">
          <li class="nav-logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/dark-logo.png" alt="Nav Logo" class="img-fluid logo-image"></a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="./index.html#about">About</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="./personal-training.html">Personal  Training</a></li>
              <li><a href="./posing-lessons.html">Posing  Lessons</a></li>
              <li><a href="./macros-calculation.html">Macros-Nutrition Calculation</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="./index.html#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="./index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="./get-started.html">Get Started</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->
```

And in the code of my front-page, im trying to get the unique header instead of the global header, this is the code of my front-page:

```html
<?php
if(is_page('front-page')) {
 get_header('new');
}
else {
 get_header();
}
 wp_head();
?>

<main id="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</main><!-- End #main -->

  <?php get_footer();?>
```

Is there a error in my PHP code? Which is the best way to get the secondary/unique header (header-new.php) instead of the global header (header.php)?

Comment: `is_page('front-page')` – not sure that is actually supposed to work here. This function takes an ID, page name or slug as argument - but probably not a page _role_ such as `front-page`. You should probably just use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/ instead here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @cBroe pointed in the comment, the problem is the `is_page()` function.

You should use `is_front_page()` [WP reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) to check if you are in the front page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {

 get_template_part( 'new_header' );

} else {

 get_header();

}

?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/